# Redirect only if file does not exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a use case where there can be HTML or PHP file in a folder but the user will only access HTML file. I was looking for htaccess redirect only if HTML file is missing. After some research, I tried below code which always redirect to php file no matter file exists or not. So if there is a file test.html then no need to redirect to test.php.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)/test.html !-f
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)/test.html?$ wp-content/uploads/$1/test.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-f` needs full filesystem path and `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` represents filename with full path for current request.

Your rule has to be written like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/[^/]+/test)\.html?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you please confirm if your RewriteRule is correct as this is not working for me?

Comment: I have tested this rule on my local Apache and it definitely works. There might be many reasons why it is not working for you e.g. presence of other rules, presence of other .htaccess files somewhere and **more importantly** presence of a framework like Wordpress that doesn't like internal rewrites.

Comment: Actually, my RewriteRule is working fine. Just thought that your might be efficient to use. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case , you want to make the priority for `.html` files then , if missing , to `.php` and force user even they request `.php` to access `.html` unless not found , so try the following code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      /$1.html   [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$      /$1.php   [L]
```

The code above will passes all `.html` and check requests without extensions first with `.html`  and also remove `.php` requests and check if there is `.html` with same name otherwise , go as it is .